# Let f be a convex differentiable function, if $\lim_{x\to +∞} f(x)=l $ then $\lim_{x\to +∞}f'(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis

What I tried to do was use the fact that f is a convex function, then
$f(x){\displaystyle \geqslant }f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$ holds for all $x_0$ in R, so for ${x\to +∞}$ we must have that $f'(x_0){\displaystyle \leqslant}0$ , however I don't really know if this is a step in the right direction and if I can finish the proof from here.

Comment: That's a good start. Use the fact that $f'$ is increasing to see $f'$ has a limit at $\infty.$ So for example if $f'>0$ anywhere then $\lim f=\infty.$ So you can rule that out.

Answer (score 5):

As you already noticed, a convex function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ “lies above” every of its tangent lines:
$$
 f(x) \ge f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x-x_0) 
$$ for all $x, x_0 \in \Bbb R$. This can be used to derive both lower and upper bounds for $f'(x_0)$, by choosing $x < x_0$ and $x > x_0$. In our case it suffices to use the inequality for $x = x_0 - 1$ and $x = x_0 + 1$. This gives
$$
 f(x_0) - f(x_0-1)  \le f'(x_0) \le f(x_0+1) - f(x_0)
$$
for all $x_0 \in \Bbb R$. Now squeeze ...

[image]

Comment: very nice proof !

Comment: It was a very nice proof, but the edit with the explanation made it even better, thanks for sharing! I like it much better than what I was going for, and I definitely couldn't have thought of this myself.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is convex with a limit at $\infty$ then $f$ is decreasing.

$f^\prime$ which is negative and increasing has a limit at $\infty$. The limit is $0$ otherwise $\lim_{x\to +∞} f(x)=-\infty$.

Comment: Why is it necessarily lim f(x)= -∞  if the limit of the derivative is not zero?

Comment: Take $a \in \mathbb R$. Then for $x>a$ you will have according to Mean value Theorem $f(x)-f(a) \le L/2(x-a)$ where $L$ would be the limit of the derivative. Hence $\lim f = - \infty$ if $L \neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a generalization of de l'Hospital rule for fractions whose numerator has a non-zero limit so: $$\lim_{x \to  \infty } \frac{f(x)}{x} =  \lim_{x \to  \infty } \frac{f'(x)}{x'} $$ The left side is of course zero.
edit: When we know the limit exist.

Comment: Note that on order to apply L'Hospital's rule you have to show that the limit on the right exists.

Comment: good point thank you